# How to show a list of information on the fly in a razor component

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I have a database and a lot of entries in a table. I want to show those entries on a webpage, using blazor.

I have tried loading the entries using `context.tableName.Load()` and `context.tableName.Local` and iterating through the entries using

```
@foreach(var entry in localList){
    <p>@entry.Name</p>
}
```

That works fine.. but it first loads all the data from the database and when it finally has finished, it starts rendering the page/results.

I want to show the results that have been loaded immediately, popping up responsive on the webpage as the loading continues. Any ideas how I would implement that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean you want to load information line by line, or you want to load data in blocks, if the former that's generally not how storage engines work because you generally load top 10 or 100 and it loads in a block and then you render it on the page. If it's that latter you may be thinking about pagination

Comment: @MarkDavies The idea was to load it line-by-line. Each time a new entry was loaded from DB and added to a Collection, the page would refresh itself and show the newly added collection item.

Comment: So generally this is a bad idea because of the way that storage engines (databases) work, generally you want to be loading records in chunks, and it's the storage engine (not the application) that loads it in one go. If you wanted to implement what you are talking about you would have to select records one by one, can you imagine how long that would take with 1000 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe matches what `IAsyncEnumerable<>` does.

Just for fun I adapted the standard starter app a little:

In WeatherForecastService :

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
{
    var rng = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 77; i++)
    {
        yield return new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(i),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        };
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

and in the FetchData.razor page:

```
List<WeatherForecast> forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await foreach (var forecast in ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now))
    {
        forecasts.Add(forecast);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

be aware that this is not a very efficent way of moving data but it might work for some scenarios.