# Loading a collection in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I'm working in Blazor preview 3.2 attempting to utilize IAsyncEnumerable in my client-side blazor-wasm project. All of my libraries are updated to the latest previews. And my code is posted below. On the server side of things I can walk through it and see it properly returning the specials.

However I see the error below in the browser console. Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

**Error**

[image]

**Client Side Code**

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   await LoadSpecials();
}

public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Special>> LoadSpecials()
{
    return await HttpClient.GetJsonAsync<IAsyncEnumerable<Special>>("api/specials");
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Special> Get()
    {
        await foreach (Special special in _db.Specials.Include(o => o.ImageFile).AsAsyncEnumerable())
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            yield return special;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another [sample answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310068/60761).